# SAPUI5 upload file and oData response

Tags: jquery, ajax, odata, sapui5

I am developing a SAPUI5 in order to upload files [mainly XML ].
I have implemented the view using XML views within the WebIDE as well as the corresponding JS controller,
which is calling an oData service matched with 'create_stream' method then doing the job of reading the file content.

All is working fine but then I cannot receive the response containing the file content [parsed] from the oData back to my js controller.

Here is my ajax call, actually there are two calls but the first one is used to get the necessary security csrf token only.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: Service1,
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", "Fetch");
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        token = XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader("X-CSRF-Token");
    }
});
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
});
jQuery.ajax({
    url: service_url,
    async: false,
    dataType: "text",
    cache: false,
    data: filedata,
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/text;charset=UTF-8");
    },
    success: function (odata) {
        oDialog.setTitle("File Uploaded");
        oDialog.open();
        document.location.reload(true);
    },
    error: function (odata) {
        oDialog.setTitle("File NOT Uploaded");
        oDialog.open();
        document.location.reload(true);
    }
});
```

Can anyone find where I am wrong within this flow ?

I think the problem might be in the ajax call, 
maybe in the parameters or in the way I am getting the data as response from the oData service ?

Or the issue could be whithin the oData create_stream method ?

Comment: It is not really clear (to me) what you are trying to do. Is the problem in receiving the data on the server side? If so, you might want to explain a bit more how your service looks like.
For using SAPUI5 with OData, you should look into the sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel for both getting and posting data.

Comment: No the problem is not in receving data on server side but on the passing of data from server [oData create_stream method] to client side [ajax response].